# Form validation not working on code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

it's my first time I'm asking in StackOverflow. so forgive me if I'm wrong and I'm new in PHP and CodeIgniter.
Okay, i have a page which serves to create new data.
I'm using form validation on CI, but it's not work like nothing happened to do if I'm filled the form or not. here is my code.

**my controller**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    /* LOAD CORE LIBRARY */
    $this->load->library('ion_auth');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    /* CHECK IF USER IS AUTHENTICATED */
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        redirect('bunker/login', 'refresh');

    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    if(empty($user->last_pwd_change)){
        redirect('bunker/account/renew', 'refresh');
    }

    /* THEN LOAD EVERYTHING ELSE */

    /* LOAD ALL NECESSARY HELPER */
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('language');

    $this->lang->load('auth');

    // Load MongoDB library instead of native db driver if required
    $this->config->item('use_mongodb', 'ion_auth') ?
    $this->load->library('mongo_db') : $this->load->database();
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters($this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth'));


    /* LOAD ALL NECESSARY MODELS */
    $this->load->model('system/company_model');
    $this->load->model('system/common_model');
    $this->load->model('website/article_model');
    $this->load->model('website/page_model');

    $this->menu['company'] = $this->company_model->getCompany();
}
function create(){
    $post = $this->input->post();
    if(!empty($post)){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('page_id', "Page Name", 'required|numeric|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('article_title', "Article Title", 'required|xss_clean');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('article_url', "Custom URL", 'xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('article_status', "Publication Status", 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('article_excerpt', "Excerpt", 'required|min_length[250]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('article_content', "Content", 'required|min_lenght[500]|xss_clean');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>','</li>');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            if(isset($_FILES['article_file'])){
                $cover = $this->common_model->uploadPicture('uploads/images/','article_file');
                $authorId   = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
                $result     = $this->article_model->addArticle($this->input->post(), $authorId, $cover);
                if($result){
                    $data = array(
                        'response'  => 'success',
                        'message'   => 'Article successfully created.'
                    );
                }else{
                    $data = array(
                        'response'  => 'error',
                        'message'   => 'Failed to create article, refresh your browser and try again.'
                    );
                }
            }else{
                $data = array(
                    'response'  => 'error',
                    'message'   => 'Please provide an image for your article.'
                );
            }
        }else{
            $data['response'] = 'error';
            $data['message']  = '<ul>';
            $data['message'] .= form_error('page_id');
            $data['message'] .= form_error('article_title');
            $data['message'] .= form_error('article_url');
            $data['message'] .= form_error('article_status');
            $data['message'] .= form_error('article_excerpt');
            $data['message'] .= form_error('article_content');
            $data['message'] .= "</ul>";
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }else{
        // DISPLAY THE PAGE
        $pages = $this->page_model->getAllPages();
        if(!$pages){
            $this->data['pages'] = NULL;
        }else{
            $this->data['pages'] = $pages;
        }

        $this->footer['status'] = "new";

        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('common/menu', $this->menu);
        $this->load->view('website/article/article_form', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('common/script', $this->footer);
        $this->load->view('common/common');
        $this->load->view('website/article/article_script');
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
}
```

**view / form**

```
<div class="block-content">
  <h2><strong>Publish</strong> New Article</h2>
  <p>Use the form below to write a new article.</p>
  <form name="article-form" id="article-form" action="<?= base_url(); ?>article/create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Page:</label>
        <select name="page_id" class="form-control">
        <option value='0' selected="selected">- Choose -</option>
        <?php if($pages != NULL): ?>
        <?php foreach($pages as $page): ?>
        <option value='<?= $page->id; ?>'><?= $page->name;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </select>
        <span class="help-block">Where do you want to publish the article.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Article Title:</label>
        <input name="article_title" id="article_title" type="text" placeholder="Title of your article" class="form-control">
        <span class="help-block">Provide a title for your article (by default, title will used for the custom url).</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Custom URL:</label>
        <input name="article_url" id="article_url" type="text" placeholder="(Optional Field)" class="form-control">
        <span class="help-block">A custom url for this article (i.e <?= base_url(); ?>my-custom-url/).</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Status:</label>
        <select name="article_status" class="form-control">
        <option value='0'>- Choose -</option>
          <option value='draft'>Draft</option>
          <option value='publish'>Published</option>
        </select>
        <span class="help-block">Assign publication status.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group file">
          <input name="article_filename" type="text" placeholder="Select image for your article" class="form-control">
          <input name="article_file" type="file">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Browse</button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Excerpt:</label>
        <textarea name="article_excerpt" id="article_excerpt" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <span class="help-block">Provide a short excerpt for your article, an excerpt may only be 1 or 2 paragraphs long.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Content:</label>
        <textarea name="article_content" id="article_content" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <span class="help-block">Provide the actual content of your article</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tags:</label>
        <input name="article_tags" id="article_tags" type="text" value="" class="form-control tagsinput">
        <span class="help-block">Provide some tag for your article</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<button type="button" onClick="submitForm();" class="btn btn-success">
```

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* SCRIPT FOR NEW ARTICLE */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#article-form').ajaxForm({                
        dataType        : 'json',
        beforeSubmit    : ShowRequest,
        success         : SubmitSuccesful,
        error           : AjaxError                        
    });
});

function submitForm(){
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $('#article-form').submit();
}

function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    return true;
}

function AjaxError(){
    // alertify.alert("An unknown error has occured, please refresh your browser.");
    noty({
        layout: 'topRight',
        text: 'Unknown error occured, please refresh your browser and try again.',
        type: 'warning'
    });
}

function SubmitSuccesful(responseText, statusText) {
    if(responseText.response == "success"){
        $('#article-form')[0].reset();
        noty({
            text: responseText.message,
            layout: 'topRight',
            type: 'success'
        });
        window.setTimeout(function(){location.href="<?=base_url()?>bunker/article"}, 2000);
    }else{
        noty({
            text: responseText.message,
            layout: 'topRight',
            type: 'error'
        });
    }
}

function articleRemove(articleId){
    noty({
    text: 'Are you sure you want to delete this page?',                                
    buttons: [
            {
                addClass: 'btn btn-danger btn-clean',
                text: 'Delete',
                onClick: function($noty) {
                    console.log("Confirmed");
                    console.log("Article ID: " + articleId);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?= base_url(); ?>bunker/article/delete/' + articleId,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data.response);
                            noty({
                                layout: 'topRight',
                                text: data.message,
                                type: 'success'
                            });
                            window.setTimeout(function(){location.href="<?=base_url()?>bunker/article"},2000);
                        },
                        failed: function(data){
                            console.log(data.response);
                            noty({
                                layout: 'topRight',
                                text: data.message,
                                type: 'error'
                            });
                        },
                        data: null
                    });
                    $noty.close();
                }
            },
            {
                addClass: 'btn btn-success btn-clean',
                text: 'Cancel',
                onClick: function($noty) {
                    $noty.close();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
</script>
```

Sorry if my English so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your controller#create() method so that you do not use the post-action check. Instead, use the Form Validation Run method.

Example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('page_id', "Page Name", 'required|numeric|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('article_title', "Article Title", 'required|xss_clean');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('article_url', "Custom URL", 'xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('article_status', "Publication Status", 'required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('article_excerpt', "Excerpt", 'required|min_length[250]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('article_content', "Content", 'required|min_lenght[500]|xss_clean');

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>','</li>');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
    // Display Succeeded Site or something else
} else {
    // Display Failed Site or Errors or something else
}
```

Comment: i was tried but still error.
automatically go to condition AjaxError.
if I'm wrong or what? but i use this code for "update" and its work.
only for create have an error like this